# Github asking for credentials only on new repositories

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I am having an issue where only new repos will ask me for credentials when pushing to my remote repos. Older repositories do not ask me for credentials.

All of my remotes (both the ones that require credentials and those that don't) are using HTTPS so I don't think it has to do with using SSH vs HTTPS.

The one thing that I think may have changed something is that I set up my SSH key on BitBucket. Ever since then, pushing/pulling from GitHub on new repos requires that I input my credentials again.

Comment: Does it ask for Github credentials? Did you try to compare the remote URLs between new and old repositories?

Comment: Yes, it asks for GitHub credentials. And the URLs for both old and new remote repositories are the same format: https://github.com/username/projectname.git

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by setting my credential helper to osxkeychain:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```